# weird uv unwrapping for a cylinder-ish object wall

Tags: uv

New to Blender, I'm following a tutorial, and supposedly I'm doing the exact steps, but the walls turn into this weird shape after UV unwrapping. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe choose the front orthogonal view and unwrap with the Cylinder Projection mode?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the vertical seam doesn't reach the top and bottom circular seams. Comparing the number of edge loops in the UV map with the ones on the 3D model, I think the model has some overlapping geometry, try to run `Mesh > Merge > By Distance` in Edit Mode with everything selected.